# Github account page from master branch or a dist branch

Tags: git, github

To create a github account site/page for the user or organization, you would create a repository like so:

```
 username.github.io
```

That is a static site, from the **master** branch. Now what I want to achieve is to *serve* the site, from the `dist` folder of the master branch, since the dist branch contains minified, concatenated assets.

I want to keep my git flow as much as possible, by following this branch model

```
master: latest production build (contains the dist folder)
develop: latest development version
```

If only if the user site could be launch from another branch, I could easily do such

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin dist-branch
```

Comment: I think [this tutorial](http://awestruct.org/auto-deploy-to-github-pages/) may be helpful. Let me know if it doesn't.